# VS Not Catching errors in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

[Error not being caught, and VS is successfully compiling it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjwwX.png)

Code

```
    <STA
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label FontSize="Medium">Enter Home Address</Label>
        <CheckBox x:Name="sw1" IsVisible="False" CheckedChanged="sw1_CheckedChanged"></CheckBox>
</StackLayout>



</StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi @saqib-nadeem, can you maybe be more expressive on what your question is? For us to be able to help you it would be good if you can clearly state your question, describe your setup, give good code example and state your expectation. At the moment it is really hard to understand your problem and to provide assistance.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project, then the error will be caught.